# jQuery resize, not performing as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am in the process of building my menu behavior and wanted to use some media queries for the jQuery.

[This is the basic functionality of the menu.](http://jsfiddle.net/3dX3T/27/) I only want this to load when the `nav ul li` are `display: block`. Once they are `inline-block`s or something else, I do not want to use `slideToggle`.

I tried using a `resize.function` as explained in [this article](http://www.fourfront.us/blog/jquery-window-width-and-media-queries), but when I do that, the `slideToggle` happens two times on click, [which you can see in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dX3T/28/).

On initial load, when you click the drop down `li` it performs as expected, but if you resize the windows then click the `li` it slide toggles two times; I am wondering why this is the case, as I very new to jQuery.

**JS**

```
$(window).resize(function(){    
    if ($("header nav ul li").css("display") == "block" ){
        $( ".dd" ).click(function() {
            $( ".submenu" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
            $( ".ar" ).toggleClass( "up" );
        });
    }
}).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: You're adding an additional click handler every time the resize handler runs.

Comment: It's rarely right to bind the handler for one event inside the handler for another event. Bind the handler globally, and have the outer handler set a variable that the inner handler checks.

Comment: I should stress that I am **very new** to jQuery, so I am not entirely sure how to do that, but thank you for the response.

Comment: The solution I posted should be a drop in fix for you. @Barmar was right about the additional click handlers; by attaching the click handler only once when the page/content loads, you can control whether or not anything happens when they are clicked using only the media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

No need to bind it to resizing, just keep it from firing unless the li elements are "block". This works, try it out.

```
$( ".dd" ).click(function() {
    if ($("header nav ul li").css("display") == "block"){
        $(this).parent().find( ".submenu" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
        $(this).find( ".ar" ).toggleClass( "up" );
    }
});
```

Comment: does that works if the browser is resized as well? [I was doing something similar](http://jsfiddle.net/3dX3T/30/) but I wanted it to account for resizes of the browser. - _edit, nvm that seems to work perfectly._

Comment: Yeah, all it does is check whether or not the "header nav ul li" display is block, and if it is, it toggles the dropdown. If it isn't then is doesn't toggle them. Basically, whenever your media query takes effect and changes to inline-block, the click event just stops toggling the dropdown.